# Heroku manual deploy keeps switching to Master

Tags: mongodb, github, heroku, mongodb-atlas

In Heroku, connected to Git. I want to deploy my Dev branch, and can select it.

When I manually deploy it does it's thing (deploys my website to Heroku). But my website has Master branch code. I go back to Heroku and it's on Master.

If I select Dev as the branch for either Manual or Automatic, then reload the page, it switches back to Master. Below is a screenshot of me setting the branch to dev. If I do a browser refresh, it resets to Master.

I tried reconnecting Github. Not sure what else it could be.
Deploying Dev was working up until yesterday.

Here is a screenshot of how I manually deploy (as opposed to auto deploy) from the Heroku Deployment tab.

[image]

Edit: I should also add, I happily was on Dev, and could deploy Dev updates up until recently. I deployed Master by mistake, bat can't go back to Dev.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you mean. What does "when I manually deploy it does it's thing... I go back to Heroku and it's on Master" mean? What does reloading the page have to do with anything?

Comment: @Chris. Added a screenshot for more context. Does that help?

Comment: It looks like it worked: "Your app was successfully deployed". Are you sure you're looking at the right app?

Comment: After this, the Heroku deploy page says its on Master. My website doesn't have the Dev code on it. I think it might be that Master is ahead of Dev by 1 commit and behind by 4.

Comment: @chris could it be related to this? https://github.com/AkhileshNS/heroku-deploy/issues/35

Comment: ...are you using that GitHub action?

Comment: No, but the last user suggests to use connected Github deployments as a way around it. But I'm seeing the same symptoms so I wonder if it's inherent to the same conditions i.e. Dev, being behind Master. Long shot I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having a corrupt Collection / DB record. I was tipped on another forum that the symptoms I was seeing (Nighscout web app not displaying some data, not the Heroku deploy I was attempting to work around that issue) could be caused by that. So as a last resort I dropped the entire Mongo Collection and I can now deploy Master and Dev, and it sticks in Heroku.

I don't know the significance since the data should be separate from the web app source code itself.

The whole reason I wanted to try Dev was for a [fix for parts of the app not working](https://github.com/nightscout/cgm-remote-monitor/pull/5704). After initialising the Mongo DB Collection, I can use Master, so Dev (and the fix it contained) is not needed.

I know this isn't the exact root cause, but I'll leave this here in case someone comes across it and hasn't thought to look at the data.

Comment: Sigh. While I solved my issue with data not displaying in the web app. The branch in Heroku is actually not sticky. I swapped back and forth between Master and Dev successfully a couple fo times. Now it's stuck on Dev, the same way.

Comment: As such I'd have to say the issues may be unrelated.

Comment: I have worked out I can make the branch stick by enabling, then disabling automatic deploys.